# Problem loading javascript files in Internet Explorer 11 when accessed using http://localhost/<...>

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a small html/javascript/jquery based application that uses Jquery Validate plugin for validation purposes. It fails to run in IE11 under certain conditions specified below

The issue is that if I try to access the application using the URL below it doesn't work

http://localhost/myapp/test.html

if I try to access the application using the URL below it works

http://127.0.0.1/myapp/test.html

if I try to access the application from another computer on the LAN

there is no problem

If I reset Internet Explorer settings fully then it starts working on Internet Explorer 11 also.

This behavior cannot be replicated on all IE 11 installed computers
Nothing additional  is installed on the problematic computers

Thanks in advance for any tips to resolve this issue

Regards
Mathew

Comment: Whether it works well on other browser, such as google and Edge? Try to open the IIS, and check the web site bindings, make sure you have added the "localhost" binding for the web site binding.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering my question myself I would like to make clarify a statement in the original problem

The statement(s)

The issue is that if I try to access the application using the URL below it doesn't work

http://localhost/myapp/test.html

if I try to access the application using the URL below it works

http://127.0.0.1/myapp/test.html

need to be read as

The issue is that if I try to access the application using the URL below Jquery files are not loaded

http://localhost/myapp/test.html

if I try to access the application using the URL below Jquery is loaded

http://127.0.0.1/myapp/test.html

This was an issue related to the Compatibility settings in Internet Explorer.
It seems that current versions of Jquery will not load in Internet Explorer when it is in Compatibility mode

Resolved the issue by adding the meta tag below to the page header

This disables the use of Compatibility settings in IE